# Castle Windsor - should I reference the container from other classes?

Tags: castle-windsor

I'm about to embark on a new project using Windsor, but I've been wondering about running into scenarios where a Class A might need to instantiate Class B, but it's not feasible or possible for Windsor to inject an instance of Class B into it. I'm struggling to think of a scenario, but here goes:

Say I have a business entity "Customer" that gets passed to a WCF service. This class has an Ent.Lib self-validation method, which in turn uses a helper class "CustomerValidator". The Customer object received by the service has been deserialized by WCF, so Windsor plays no part in its instantiation, so I can't inject any dependencies. Nor can I pass my CustomerValidator to the self-validation method as it must follow a particular signature for Ent.Lib. So how could I instantiate the CustomerValidator within this class/method? I still want to utilise Windsor rather than simply doing a "*var cv = new CustomerValidator();*".

It's not a great example as it could be solved in different ways, e.g. passing the Customer object to a validation method rather than having the validation method in the Customer class, but it offers a possible scenario for discussion.

I could expose my WindsorContainer as a public singleton, accessible by any code that needs it, but that seems to be frowned upon. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should I reference the container from other classes?

No. By referencing the container, you add complicated and unnecessary dependency to your class which will complicate testing and increase complexity.

> The Customer object received by the service has been deserialized by WCF, so Windsor plays no part in its instantiation, so I can't inject any dependencies.

I think this is the direction you should go, try to explore if there really isn't any way to take control of deserialization so you can inject dependencies.

<strike>If that fails, consider using http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/. Its Microsoft's service location implementation with Windsor adapter available. It's basically the same pattern as if you referenced the container but you don't introduce dependency on specific container implementation. Also I think it will be easier to mock for testing.</strike>

Comment: CommonServiceLocator is a pain in the ass and it's mute point; not being dependent on a specific IoC anyway, because now you are not just dependent on ONE, but TWO "IoC" container. Also, there's a long-standing bug in checking for non-initialized CSL singletons that isn't being fixed by pnp. It seems you can [hook into WCF somewhere](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx). Furthermore, the CSL code won't call `Release` and without the non-tracking Windsor policy, you'll keep refs to all resolved objects that way.

Comment: good point, I did consider not mentioning CSL or SL at all, now I know why